# get positions of true within array of booleans

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

So in this table,  Each row of the table contains sales data for a product (car, train, or plane) from January through July. Suppose you enter a month and a product into the worksheet. Write a formula that gives the total sales of that product during the given month.
so, in this case, I tried to use array functions in excel 2016, I tried to use the exact function to get positions of "car" in the product column, like this  =exact("car", product)  and by using ctrl shift enter we get values of true and false, now we want to find a position of true values and sum up its corresponding sales in a concrete month,
I am trying to use offset function and match function to find the position of the month but it's hard to find the multiple positions of the car. how can we solve it?

Comment: If you can restructure your data to unpivot months into a single column then you could just create a pivot table to do the work. You already have multiple rows with the same product in the product column. You can use Power Query to unpivot the month columns.

Comment: You could also try `SUMPRODUCT()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `K3`, enter formula :

```
=SUMIF(A:A,K1,INDEX(1:1,MATCH(K2,1:1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, I forgot the principle of sumif, sumif with one array gives a position of true values and with sum range I could've summed up the desired results(the results corresponding to positions of true within array) . thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(FILTER(INDEX(B1:C5,,XMATCH(A8,B1:C1)),A1:A5=A7))` when using Office 365 or
`=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--(A2:A5=A7),--(B1:C1=A8)),B2:C5)` (confirmed with `ctrl+shift+enter`) for prior versions.

[image]

Change the ranges to match your ranges.

Comment: thanks for sharing great concept <3